# Application database model

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, ios6

I've seen a couple of projects so far and realised that there're projects that make no use of foreign keys (tables are thus not linked), whereas there're projects which tables are indeed linked.

I'm developing an application for `iOS` using `SQLITE3`, and **which one is the best practice** when it comes to developing an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having FKs is a little bit like having managed memory - the system itself will never let you make a "dangling pointer", no matter how seriously you err in your application's implementation.

Foreign keys are essential for maintaining data integrity. They are:

- **Declarative:** This makes them "obvious" and more self-documenting than the imperative code buried in the depths of the application's implementation.
- **Robust:** Merely *one* buggy application could corrupt the data, so it's crucial to have a central mechanism for enforcing data integrity that *cannot be circumvented* by the applications.
- **Scalable:** In a *concurrent* environment, implementing FKs correctly requires appropriate concurrency control (such as locking), which can typically be done much more efficiently in the DBMS than it would be possible at the application level.

In all honesty, this is not as crucial in embedded databases such as SQLite, as it is in the "big" client-server databases where multiple client applications routinely access the same database. However, there is no downside to using FKs in the embedded environment either, so you should do it whenever you're not too limited by historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to have foreign keys. Personally the idea of having no foreign keys in a relational database is foreign to me. (excuse the pun)  Foreign keys help to enforce referential integrity.

Comment: I always learned this way in University, but this is not what I see in enterprises...

Comment: Yes, I know.  as  Gilbert Le Blanc stated some of this comes from legacy systems, and some of it comes from developers leaving them out because they were lazy or during development they were too restrictive/cumbersome and then never getting around to putting them in

Answer (score 0):

In the distant past, applications were built on a hierarchical or network database that did not have foreign keys as a part of the database.  The foreign keys had to be coded in the application.

These applications were eventually migrated to relational databases, after much kicking and screaming.  I'm helping to maintain an application that was migrated from IDMS to DB2 in 2011.

The code wasn't changed, and developers continued to maintain foreign keys as a part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing an app for iOS, in your case, Object Model Design and Database (Table) design will go hand it hand (then data plumbing code becomes a lot easy. Otherwise you have to tweak your data plumbing code anytime you make changes in your application). With that being said, wherever you have a parent-child relation ship in your object (one-one or one-many mapping) they should be stored inside your in a foreign key table. The 'parent' object goes to Primary table. the 'Child' object goes into Foreign key table.

If you requirement is fairly simple, you can also consider storing the information as XML. Then you don't need to worry about the DB schema design. One useful link for your consideration

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1019623

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why rails framework doesn't seem to make those relationships on the database as well. He uses Active Record to do those relationships.